# Error posting to URL: appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create - 404

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have created a maven google app engine project from [appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java). My project includes Rest webservices, Java, JPA and Hibernate.

Locally everything (rest webservices and database connection) working perfect. But when I try to deploy my code ...

I have a problem exactly same as [Error posting to URL: appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create - 404](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5683).

I tried all possible ways (enlisted in above [link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5683)) to solve it but unable to solve it.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I have gone through many links but no luck, but now I am able to solve it using following step(s)

1. You must be signed in in the eclipse with a google account.
   (already done)
2. You must configure cloud sql (if you are using database - mysql
   in my case) (already done)
3. After that run maven command something like `mvn appengine:update` (already done)
4. **Permissions**. ( This is where I stuck ). Open the project on
   google app engine https://console.cloud.google.com/ . Goto *IAM &
   Admin*, select project then permissions. After that you see that
   your email id (say `abcd@gmail.com`) will be listed as an owner and another(dummy) email
   address like `664581334627-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
   and/or `664581334627@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`. Give all
   above 3 email addresses rights of **Project Editor** and **App
   Engine Deployer**.

After this run `mvn appengine:update` and you will see there will be no exception/error. And you code will be deployed successfully.

**P.S.:** *already done* means that in original post I have already done these steps, but just wanted to let you know all possible steps.